# Save a Graphics Interchange Format

Tags: gif

How can I save the gif "Graph of Tangent from Unit circle" on:

http://www.mathwarehouse.com/unit-circle/graph-and-formula-unit-circle.php

?

Thank you.

Comment: Right Click > Save As ? (works in Firefox)

Comment: or just drag it to the desktop...

Comment: This website needs Java to work.